# Small webpage shift, need to revise a CSS rule

Tags: html, css

I have a web page I am testing that is doing a slight shift to the left when I click on "Solutions". To toggle back and forth go to "Solutions" and then the logo.

http://jmcintosh.aisites.com/TRS/index.html

I know exactly what the problem is in my CSS. It's the "div.breakright ul li" for the orange dotted list items in the "Solutions" page.

I've tried multiple different ways but can not get the page to stop shifting.

Need another set of eyes or another way to apply it, look at it.

Comment: What browser is having the issue - it seems to be working fine in Chrome 15

Comment: Is it the image flicker in the nav that you're concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shifting left because of the scroll-bar. You only notice this shift when other pages don't require scrolling. This isn't a CSS issue, but you can make it unnoticeable via CSS.

html {overflow-y:scroll;}

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, but if the scrollbar is the problem, I prefer `html { height: 101%; }` to force the scrollbar to always show.

Comment: The problem with using `html{height:101%;}` is that it not only forces a scroll-bar, but it also forces a minimal amount of scrolling, even when a page doesn't require it. In other words, it looks tacky. Why should a user be capable of scrolling when there is no content to create a natural scroll?

So, just to be clear...

`html {height:101%;}` forces scroll-bar **and** creates unnecessary scrolling

`html {overflow-y:scroll;}` forces scroll-bar only